# Difference between `bx` and `bp`?

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

What is the difference between `bx` and `bp` in assembly? Example here:

```
mov bx, 1h
mov bp, 1h
```

Do they reference to the same memory? Is it the same with `ss` and `sp`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In `x86` the registers `bx` and `bp` are totally unrelated. The only common thing about them is the word `base`.

- `bx` **(base index)** is a general-purpose register (like ax, cx and dx), typically used as a pointer to data (used for arrays and such)
- `bp` **(base pointer)** is typically used to point at some place in the stack (for instance holding the address of the current stack frames)

Again, `ss` and `sp` are different as well.

- `ss` **(stack segment)** is a segment register (like cs, ds and es). It holds the [segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation) used by the stack.
- `sp` **(stack pointer)** points at the top of the stack

Comment: If stack is empty, do `ss` point to same place as `sp` and thank you!?

Comment: @tina nyaa Like I said, `ss` and `sp` are totally unrelated (you need to follow that link on x86 segmentation). There is a relationship between `sp` and `bp`.

Comment: additionally the behaviour in 16 bit is a little different. [BX] uses segment DS so it points to the address DS:BX while [BP] uses segment SS, so it points to SS:BP.

Comment: and you need to understand segment addressing. SS:SP points to the current top of the stack. Take SS shift it 4 bits to the left and add SP and voila you got the 20 bit linear address. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation for more information

Answer (score 0):

BP  register  mainly  helps  in  referencing  the parameter  variables  passed  to  a  subroutine.  The  address  in  SS  register  is combined  with  the  offset  in  BP  to  get  the  location  of  the  parameter.  BP  can also  be  combined  with  DI  and  SI  as base register for  special  addressing.

BX:   used in index and indirect addressing